# How can I see all the attributes of a queryset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have this code using Django :

```
a = Clients.objects.get(id=1)
```

And I would like to display all the attributes of `a`.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

`a = Clients.objects.filter(id=1).values()`